# Is it possible to get the price a token is trading for without the use or oracles

Tags: tokens, smart-contract-wallets

Is it possible to get the price a token is trading for without the use or oracles. like somehow make the smart contract look at a DEX and get the price that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Most DEX have a "getQuote" function or, for uniswap v2's case, a getAmountOut() function that let you preview the 'price' of a token compared to it's token pair, but that's really unsafe since you are relaying on a price on a pair on one DEX at one block height, so it's super vulnerable to price manipulation.

Comment: can you elaborate on the "one block height " vulnerability a little bit more

Comment: Oracles use averages of price accross multiple DEX and often averages accross multiples block, meaning they check the price of a pair on the last, lets say, 5 blocks to see the evolution of price. Otherwise, if its a price check at instant T, now, someone could manipulate the price with a flash loan by providing a lot of tokens on one side and skew the price. Makes more sense?

Comment: Devon? Also, if my answer was useful, you should mark it as valid. Thanks